# Integration tests: MembershipProvider - TypeLoadException

Tags: asp.net, tdd, asp.net-membership

Am trying to write some tests that create/remove/change users using a CustomMembershipProvider. The CustomMembershipProvider is part of the WebApp assembly.

When I run my test I get the following exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'WebApp.Framework.CustomMembershipProvider' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, ref StackCrawlMark stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Web.Security.Membership.InitializeSettings(Boolean initializeGeneralSettings, RuntimeConfig appConfig, MembershipSection settings)
   at System.Web.Security.Membership.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Security.Membership.get_Providers()
   at System.Web.Security.MembershipUser..ctor(String providerName, String name, Object providerUserKey, String email, String passwordQuestion, String comment, Boolean isApproved, Boolean isLockedOut, DateTime creationDate, DateTime lastLoginDate, DateTime lastActivityDate, DateTime lastPasswordChangedDate, DateTime lastLockoutDate)
   at BusinessLayer.Users.UserRepository.Add(User user, ref MembershipCreateStatus status) in UserRepository.cs: line 43
   at WebApp.Framework.CustomMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, ref MembershipCreateStatus status) in CustomMembershipProvider.cs: line 86
   at Tests.Framework.CustomMembershipProviderTests.CreateUser() in CustomMembershipProviderTests.cs: line 22
```

The exception is thrown when I execute this line of code:

```
        return new MembershipUser(
            "MyMembershipProvider",
            user.Name,
            null,
            user.EmailAddress,
            string.Empty,
            string.Empty,
            true,
            false,
            DateTime.MinValue,
            DateTime.MinValue,
            DateTime.MinValue,
            DateTime.MinValue,
            DateTime.MinValue);
```

In my test project the following lines are added to my app.conf:

the membership definition:

```
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="WebApp.Framework.CustomMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
```

the database connection:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=WS050129\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Users;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

It looks good to me, but apparently something is off :). Could anybody point me in the right direction? Kinda clueless here.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have added a reference to your project or the assembly is in the bin directory?  Also, i might be going a bit mad here as its been a long day, but if you are hitting the database you are not unit testing (you are doing integration tests) and if you are not unit testing you are not doing TDD, you should be mocking/stubbing out the calls to database.

Comment: long day short day, even still, you're right :). changed the title. Ann L solved my prob. thx for the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
<add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="WebApp.Framework.CustomMembershipProvider"       connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
```

... to this:

```
<add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="WebApp.Framework.CustomMembershipProvider, WebApp" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
```

You may need to tweak that a little.  But it looks like the problem is that, lacking information about what assembly the type is in, the framework is looking in `System.Web`.  Flesh out the type definition attribute on that tag.

Comment: Hah! That's spot on milady. Thanks a lot (I would never have found that myself!) Tests runs fine, and my first record just appeared in my table :). Thanks again!